# как сделать переключение вида графика по кнопке в JS

Tags: javascript

есть график MyChart

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

вот его отрисовка:

```
let ctx = document.querySelector('#myChart').getContext('2d');
    let chart_type = 'line' 
    let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: chart_type, // ТУТ ДОЛЖНО МЕНЯТЬСЯ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ  
        data: {
            labels: arrDate,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Потрачено',
                data: sortPrice,
                backgroundColor: [
                    '#6fcdcd',
                    '#ff829d',
                    '#ffd778'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'black',

                ],
                borderWidth: 2
            }]
        },
        options: {

        }
    })
```

есть кнопка:

```
<input type="submit" id="remove" class="btn btn-success" value="Другой график">
```

есть переменная let chart_type = 'line', как мне сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, значение chart_type менялось на chart_type = 'bar' и обратно, так чтобы прошлое значение было не актуально и график поменялся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, это поможет:

```
let cntr=0;
document.getElementById("remove"). addEventListener ("click", function(){
cntr=(cntr+1)%2;
let chart_type = cntr%2==0?'line' :'bar';
    let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: chart_type,
        data: {
            labels: arrDate,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Потрачено',
                data: sortPrice,
                backgroundColor: [
                    '#6fcdcd',
                    '#ff829d',
                    '#ffd778'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'black',

                ],
                borderWidth: 2
            }]
        },
        options: {

        }
    })
})
```